# jQuery - How to get elements height value and use it in another element via css code?

Tags: jquery, css, height, element

I want to get height ( or width.. doesnt really matter ) from `element A` and use that height to set css to `element B` ...like

```
$('#element_B').css({ 'top','element_A_height' })
```

A little example here.. I know the javascript is not even close to something that works, I just tried to explain what i wanted to happen..

http://jsfiddle.net/cJdXg/

I have no idea how to achieve this.. any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/cJdXg/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="BoxeeBox">Lorem ipsum dolor. #boxeeBox</div>
<div id="emptyBox1">#emptyBox1</div>
<div id="emptyBox2">#emptyBox2</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var BoxeeBox = $('#BoxeeBox'); /* cache the selector */

$('#emptyBox1').css({ width: BoxeeBox.width() });
$('#emptyBox2').css({ height: BoxeeBox.height() });
```

CSS:

```
div { background: #b6d754; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px; margin: 5px; float: left; clear: both; border-radius:10px; }
```

Comment: to get this to work I had to put quotes around width and height like so: `.css({ 'width': BoxeeBox.width() })`

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is this:

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Example:

```
var elementAheight = $('#elementA').height();
```

however, if elementA has margins you may want to us this:

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Example:

```
var elementAoutheight = $('#elementA').outerHeight();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

have u seen these functions and examples given below the functions, this might helps u

http://api.jquery.com/height/

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element_B').css("top", $("#element_a").css("top"));
```

But i suggest to cache it first, and reuse for other case

```
var topVal = $("#element_a").css("top");
 $('#element_B').css("top", topVal);
 $('#element_C').css("top", topVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like

```
$("#elemA").height( $("#elemB").height() );
```